# Obtaining list of unique pixel values in OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, matrix, computer-vision

Is there an equivalent of `np.unique()` or `bincount()` for an OpenCV `Mat`? I am working with C++ so can't just convert to a `numpy` array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No, there is not!** You can code your own, though:

```
std::vector<float> unique(const cv::Mat& input, bool sort = false)
```

> Find the unique elements of a single channel cv::Mat.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> *input*: It will be treated as if it was 1-D.
>
> *sort*: Sorts the unique values (optional).

The implementation of such function is pretty straight forward, however, the following only works with **single channel** `CV_32F`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> unique(const cv::Mat& input, bool sort = false)
{
    if (input.channels() > 1 || input.type() != CV_32F) 
    {
        std::cerr << "unique !!! Only works with CV_32F 1-channel Mat" << std::endl;
        return std::vector<float>();
    }

    std::vector<float> out;
    for (int y = 0; y < input.rows; ++y)
    {
        const float* row_ptr = input.ptr<float>(y);
        for (int x = 0; x < input.cols; ++x)
        {
            float value = row_ptr[x];

            if ( std::find(out.begin(), out.end(), value) == out.end() )
                out.push_back(value);
        }
    }

    if (sort)
        std::sort(out.begin(), out.end());

    return out;
}
```

**Example:**

```
float data[][3] = {
  {  9.0,   3.0,  7.0 },
  {  3.0,   9.0,  3.0 },
  {  1.0,   3.0,  5.0 },
  { 90.0, 30.0,  70.0 },
  { 30.0, 90.0,  50.0 }
};

cv::Mat mat(3, 5, CV_32F, &data);

std::vector<float> unik = unique(mat, true);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < unik.size(); i++)
    std::cout << unik[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

**Outputs:**

```
1 3 5 7 9 30 50 70 90
```

Comment: why don't you use `std::set`?

Comment: @Shai It seems a good idea initially, it probably is faster from the performance point of view since it's guaranteed to store unique values. It renders useless the `std::find()` I placed in the code and it will br great if your `cv::Mat` is single channel and you need to store an integer. **However**, if you need to store `cv::Vec3b` (a pixel) or other complex data types, `std::vector` might be better suited for the job. `std::set` stores values in a specific order, and one might want to reorganize these values in a different fashion, thus `std::vector` in the answer.

Comment: I'm not passionate about `std::vector`. Depending on how much flexibility you need in the storage/ordering point of view, `std::set` could be enough and probably a faster solution. I'm not worrying too much about performance in these answers simply because it's a subject that is not relevant to the question. I try to be as didactic as possible without getting into too many details at first.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to build a histogram with number of bins equal to number of possible pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion for an implementation using the standard library.

`opencv-unique.cpp`

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>

/**
 * @brief Find unique elements of an OpenCV image
 *
 * @tparam type is the C++ type to access the image elements.
 * @param in is the OpenCV single-channel image to find the unique values. Note: This
 * modifies the image. Make a copy with .clone(), if you need the image afterwards.
 *
 * @returns vector of unique elements
 */
template<typename type>
std::vector<type> unique(cv::Mat in) {
    assert(in.channels() == 1 && "This implementation is only for single-channel images");
    auto begin = in.begin<type>(), end = in.end<type>();
    auto last = std::unique(begin, end);    // remove adjacent duplicates to reduce size
    std::sort(begin, last);                 // sort remaining elements
    last = std::unique(begin, last);        // remove duplicates
    return std::vector<type>(begin, last);
}

int main() {
    cv::Mat img = (cv::Mat_<uint16_t>(3, 4) << 1, 5, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 1, 3, 4, 3);

    std::cout << "unique values: ";
    auto u = unique<uint16_t>(img);
    for (auto v : u)
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and execute yields:

```
$ g++ -Wall opencv-unique.cpp -o unique -lopencv_core -I /usr/include/opencv4 && ./unique
unique values: 1 3 4 5
```

The version above is for single-channel images. You can extend this to multi-channel images (to get unique colors), like [this](https://gist.github.com/JohnWayne1986/e1aee3154d14aa3597ad0e69479838e8).