# How to differentiate between binary and gray-scale images?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working with grayscale images. I´m looking for a way to filter images that have predominantly near black and near white pixels from those images that mostly have gray pixels.

Currently, I´m doing:

1. Applying threshold for filtering B/W pixels from grey ones.
2. Compare the count of blacks plus the count of whites against pixels total of the image.

Is it there any other way for solving this? Maybe an existing OpenCV method?

**EDIT** Here's my implementation of the above.

```
bool isBinary(cv::Mat img)
{
    cv::Mat whites, blacks;
    unsigned int count_whites=0, count_blacks=0, count_pixels=0;

    // White enough goes to full white (255)
    cv::threshold(img, whites, 250, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    // Not black enough goes to full white (255)
    cv::threshold(img, blacks, 5, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

    cv::MatIterator_<unsigned char> it_whites = whites.begin<unsigned char>(), it_whites_end = whites.end<unsigned char>();
    cv::MatIterator_<unsigned char> it_blacks = blacks.begin<unsigned char>();

    for (; it_whites != it_whites_end; ++it_whites, ++it_blacks) {
        unsigned char current_white=*it_whites, current_black=*it_blacks;
        // Checking white
        if ((int)*it_whites == 255)
            count_whites++;
        // Checking black
        if ((int)*it_blacks == 0)
            count_blacks++;
        count_pixels++;
    }

    // Let's say 80% its predominantly binary for me
    return (count_blacks + count_whites) > 0.8*count_pixels;
}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking? Did your "currently I´m trying" solution fail? work? error?

Comment: Doesn't your approach in 2. work? It seems reasonable. It's up to you what "predominantly" exactly mean for you. Maybe that is interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716932/obtaining-list-of-unique-pixel-values-in-opencv-mat

Comment: 1- compute a histogram with 255 bins
2- compute ratio of bin[0]+bin[254] / sum(bin)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to decide what you are doing.

An image may be full grayscale - pixels in a range 0-255 with most numbers represented, full binary - all pixels 0 or 255, binary with anti aliasing - pixels 0 or 255, except at boundaries, where intermediate values are allowed, essentially binary - most values near 0 or 255 but not exactly 0 or 255. There are maybe other possibilities.

Look up Otsu thresholding, which will be a useful technique for separating an image into foreground and background. Then decide what you will call "black and white" and what you will call "greyscale".

Comment: **black and white** Images with most of their pixels value near/equal to 0 or 255.
**greyscale** Images with most of their pixels value NOT near/equal to 0 or 255.

Comment: So it's just a histogram, with a bit of logic. Otsu threshold it, then take the two modes. If they are outside of tolerance, it is grey. Then take pixels more than tolerance outside of the kmodes. If more than, say, 10%, it's grey. So you need four parameters: tolerance for "white", tolerance for "black", tolerance for "equal to mode" and "percent allowed outside mode"